# How do I sort colors in the color table in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, transparency

I'm using adobe photoshop cs version 8.0.

Using the menu: Image > Mode > Color Table, I'm trying to make some colors transparent.

The problem is that the range of colors I need to pick is scattered all over the color table. How do I sort the colors in the color table according to saturation to ease my work?

In the picture below, the background should be transparent so that only the lady's face and hair should be extracted.

[image: color table used for indexed image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. File → Save for web
2. Change format to .gif

[image: Save for Web as GIF]

3. Use drop down menu in color swatch to Sort by Hue. Its not the Metadata which appears selected in Image. Its the arrow and three lines next to Color Table that you want to drop down.

[image]

4. Save the Color Table in the same drop down

[image: Save for Web as GIF]

5. Now you can load it into your Swatch panel. Probably best to use "Replace" so you don't have the original swatches as well.

**Note:** Of course if you're making transparent... aren't you already in the Save for Web dialog? In which case just use the drop down menu to order them.